# Pandas to_csv output column names as string instead of converting to datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with column names like:

```
DEC2021, JAN2022, FEB2022, etc.
```

When using to_csv, I find that these column names are automatically converted to datetime object like :

```
12/1/2021, 1/1/2022, 2/1/2022, etc.
```

I wonder if there is an option to keep these column names as it is with to_csv?

Comment: How did you check that these column names are converted to the shown format? Did you open the CSV in excel? The conversion is likely due to excel, try opening the CSV in a **text** editor.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggested solution using `.to_excel()` function:

First, let's create a pandas dataframe with the provided column names:

```
# importing packages 
import pandas as pd 
  
# dictionary of data 
dct = {'DEC2021': {0:0}, 
      'JAN2022': {0:0}, 
      'FEB2022': {0:0}
    } 
  
# forming dataframe
data = pd.DataFrame(dct)
```

After this, it is possible to use `columns` arguments for `.to_csv()` function, where the value assigned would be the dataframe column names (`data.columns`)

```
# storing into the excel file
data.to_excel("output.xlsx", columns=data.columns)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @AlvaroMartinez, it's actually working for to_excel but not for to_csv or to_clipboard.